Question about the support of a normal weight on a von Neumann algebra
Consider the following fragment from Stratila's book "Modular theory in operator algebras":

I understand everything in this fragment, except that equation $(3)$ holds. How can one show this equality?
Thanks in advance for your help!

One can show this holds when $\varphi(x) < \infty$ using the fact that $\varphi$ extends to a linear functional on a suitable subspace and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I’m not sure how to prove the general case though.

I'll use Haagerup's theorem on normal weights (Theorem 1.3 in Stratila's book). Take $x\in M^+$. Then
$$ \varphi(s(\varphi) x s(\varphi))=\sup_{0\le f \le \varphi} f(s(\varphi) x s(\varphi)).$$
where $\sup_{0\le f \le \varphi}$ runs over $f\in M_*^+$ such that $f(y)\le \varphi(y)$ for $y\in M^+$. For such $f$, due to $1=s(\varphi)+e_0$ we have
$$ f(s(\varphi)x s(\varphi))=f(x)+f(e_0 x e_0) -f(e_0 x)-f(x e_0).$$
Now, by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$ |f(e_0 x)|\le f(e_0^* e_0)^{1/2} f(x^*x)^{1/2}=f(e_0)^{1/2} f(x^*x)^{1/2} \le \varphi(e_0)^{1/2} f(x^*x)=0$$
as $\varphi(e_0)=0$ and $f(x^*x)<+\infty$. Similarly $f(xe_0)=0$ and $f(e_0 x e_0)=0$. Thus
$$ \varphi(s(\varphi)x s(\varphi))=\sup_{0\le f\le \varphi}  f(x)=\varphi(x)$$
again by normality of $\varphi$.
